# Delete multiple special characters in string

Tags: dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I'm new in Dynamics 365 Business Central and AL. I need to delete special characters from a string (email address, phone numbers). I tried `DELCHR(String,'=','[')`, but there are more chars forbidden. I know I can add more than one, but I don't know if I caught them all. Can anyone please help me with a more efficient way? Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write a function which keeps the 'good' characters, like:

```
local procedure DeleteSpecialChars(var yourText: Text)
var
    AllowedChars: Text;
begin
    AllowedChars := 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-0123456789';
    exit(DelChr(yourText, '=', DELCHR(yourText, '=', AllowedChars)));
end;
```

I assume you develope for BC V14 or later. If so, you can use the codeunit 47 *StringConversionManagement* methods *RemoveNonAlphaNumericCharacters* or  *RemoveDecimalFromString*.

For email addresses you should use codeunit 9520 *Mail Management*. It holds a function which validates email addresses (*CheckValidEmailAddress*).